# Demonstrating microservices in spring and eclipse is not working

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to build a proof of concept for microservices in java (eclipse) using Spring libraries and following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBkD-OBeL0s) tutorial.

Due to certain restrictions, I am not using Maven, but I rather downloaded the following jar files manually and imported them to my java project.

[image: spring libraries being used]

My java code is very simple as the following:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    //http://localhost:port/
    String hello()
    {
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class,args);
    }


}
```

**The problem is:** When I run the code, the server does **NOT** start, but no errors are there, except the following output, and the application shuts down instantly:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2019-08-29 09:41:17.999  INFO 14096 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : Starting HelloWorld on HQTPM146609D with PID 14096 (D:\Ramesh\ADMWorkspace\HelloWorldMicroservice\build\classes started by abdallah.alhodaly in D:\Ramesh\ADMWorkspace\HelloWorldMicroservice)
2019-08-29 09:41:18.002  INFO 14096 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-29 09:41:18.078  INFO 14096 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3d36e4cd: startup date [Thu Aug 29 09:41:18 GST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-08-29 09:41:19.408  INFO 14096 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-08-29 09:41:19.426  INFO 14096 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : Started HelloWorld in 1.86 seconds (JVM running for 2.504)
2019-08-29 09:41:19.430  INFO 14096 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3d36e4cd: startup date [Thu Aug 29 09:41:18 GST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-08-29 09:41:19.432  INFO 14096 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

How can I fix my code so that the message Hello World!!! is displayed on the web page? Thank You.

**Update: Following the below answer, I set the context of my application to WebApplicationType.SERVLET. Now, I am getting the following errors:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2019-08-29 11:03:28.515  INFO 9416 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : Starting HelloWorld on HQTPM146609D with PID 9416 (D:\Ramesh\ADMWorkspace\HelloWorldMicroservice\build\classes started by abdallah.alhodaly in D:\Ramesh\ADMWorkspace\HelloWorldMicroservice)
2019-08-29 11:03:28.518  INFO 9416 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorld                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-29 11:03:28.616  INFO 9416 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@62e136d3: startup date [Thu Aug 29 11:03:28 GST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-08-29 11:03:29.521  WARN 9416 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2019-08-29 11:03:29.534  INFO 9416 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-29 11:03:29.542 ERROR 9416 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at hello.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:29) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Comment: you shall use a browser and hit your web app

Comment: @Sanjeev, not working. "This site can't be reached".

Answer (score 0):

In main class, you need write "SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class,args);"

Comment: that doesn't change the output much, and the server is still not running.

Comment: I don't see errors. Only this line appeared now at the end: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Your application context is wrong, it should of web application context. To fix this try either of these
setApplicationContextClass(…) or setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType) using SpringApplication.

Comment: It should be of AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext instead of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext

Comment: I am unable to see or access this method in the class SpringApplication.

Comment: These are instance method you can call

Comment: SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MySpringConfiguration.class);
 app.setxxxxx

Comment: MySpringConfiguration.class is undefined. Can you please provide a complete code ?

Comment: Replace it with class name marked with @SpringBootApplication it may be HelloWorldApplication

Comment: done. What about AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext argument in the context setting? How should I define it or use it?

Comment: edit main method and replace with :
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(HelloWorldApplication.class);
  app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.SERVLET);
  app.run(args);

Comment: Thanks. Now I got this error: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.